# How to get automatic color change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

Once root button is clicked how can I get the other buttons to automatically change from black to respective color without the user clicking on the button? Should the other circles not be a button? Can I have the circles change color in 2 seconds after the root button has been clicked? Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikole/rrxXN/4/)

```
<div class="interactiveBox">
<button id="root" onclick="changeColor(this,'#ff0000')" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="sacral" onclick="changeColor(this,'orange')" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="solar" onclick="changeColor(this,'yellow')" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="heart" onclick="changeColor(this,'green')" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="throat" onclick="changeColor(this,'blue')" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="third" onclick="changeColor(this,'purple')" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="crown" onclick="changeColor(this,'white')" style="background-color: black"></button>
```

```
function changeColor(obj,color) {
    //reset other buttons
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000000" ;
    }
    obj.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
```

Comment: You were almost there with the loop, you just need to store the desired color as an attribute, rather than just in the function call, then you can access it in your loop. See my answer for details.

Comment: Can you give a fiddle example of what scenario you want? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JSFiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/4t89D/2/

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

```
<div class="interactiveBox">
    <button id="root"   onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="#ff0000"></button>
    <button id="sacral" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="orange"></button>
    <button id="solar"  onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="yellow"></button>
    <button id="heart"  onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="green"></button>
    <button id="throat" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="blue"></button>
    <button id="third"  onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="purple"></button>
    <button id="crown"  onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="white"></button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor(obj) {
    //reset other buttons
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){      
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000000" ;
    }
    obj.style.backgroundColor=obj.getAttribute('data-color');
    if(obj.id == "root"){
        setTimeout(changeAllcolors,2000);
    }
}
function changeAllcolors(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        var color = buttons[i].getAttribute('data-color');
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your JS Fiddle is exactly what I'm looking for. Your code give me a better understanding of what it is I'm trying to do. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically trigger a click on your other buttons. Also, if you want to do that after 2 seconds, use setTimeout:

```
document.getElementById('root').addEventListener("click", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".interactiveBox button:not(#root)").forEach(function() {
      this.click();
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: It seems a bit convoluted to trigger events on the other buttons when you only really need a single event and a loop.

Comment: @beeglebug that's a way to solve the given problem without editing the Html. Indeed we could rewrite the whole thing, maybe use jQuery, rethink with ruby or render it server side.

Comment: If OP is happily editing the Javascript I assumed he would not be allergic to also editing the markup to use a much more sensible approach.

Comment: Between this answer and the one suggesting data attributes, they can choose between quick and dirty ... and slower but cleaner. So we're all happy right?

Comment: I agree the solution using data is more clean, yet as is it doesn't respect the 2s wait requirement and forces the use of jQuery which is absolutely not necesarry for a context that trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the target color of each button as a data attribute, then in the onclick event of the root button, loop through the other buttons, access the data attribute, and set the color appropriately.

**HTML**

```
<button id="root" class="colorChange" onclick="changeColor()" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="sacral" class="colorChange" data-color="orange" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="solar" class="colorChange" data-color="yellow" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="heart" class="colorChange" data-color="green' style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="throat" class="colorChange" data-color="blue')style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="third" class="colorChange" data-color="purple" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="crown" class="colorChange" data-color="white' style="background-color: black"></button>
```

**Javascript (jQuery for simplicity)**

```
function changeColor() {
    $('button.colorChange').each(function(button) {
        $(button).css({ 'background-color' : $(button).data('color') });
    });
}
```